# Why not working query orderby using generic method interface inheritance

Tags: .net, linq

The orderbydescending not working if inherit the T type class using interface implementation.
But it work if i do inherit concrete class of the interface(Isort).

```
     My interface: 
        public interface ISorter
            {
                IQueryable<T> NewsSort<T>(IQueryable<T> query) where T : ISort;
            }

Type class:
    public FinalResults : ISort
    {

      public  DateTime NewsDate{ get; set; }
    }

Implementation:
public class NewsSorter : ISorter
                    {
                public IQueryable<T> NewsSort<T>(IQueryable<T> query) 
               where T : ISort
                        {
                          query = query.OrderByDescending(p => p.NewsDate);
                        }
                  }
```

Comment: Can you write LinQ query?

Comment: You don't show the code for `ISort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect your `NewsSort` to magically work out what interface implementation you passed to it and then modify a property on said implementation, which simply isn't possible.

You have to add `NewsDate` as property to the interface `ISort` so it's shared between implementations and can be accessed that way!

```
public interface ISort
{
    DateTime NewsDate { get; set; }
}

public interface ISorter
{
    IQueryable<T> NewsSort<T>(IQueryable<T> query) where T : ISort;
}

public class FinalResults : ISort
{
    public DateTime NewsDate { get; set; }
}

public class NewsSorter : ISorter
{
    public IQueryable<T> NewsSort<T>(IQueryable<T> query) where T : ISort
    {
        return query.OrderByDescending(p => p.NewsDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Guys.I have implemented Isort but mistake am overriding the query rather than return.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to overwrite a parameter passed to the method.

Adjust the code in the implementation so it looks like this:

```
public class NewsSorter : ISorter
{
    public IQueryable<T> NewsSort<T>(IQueryable<T> query) 
        where T : ISort
    {
        return query.OrderByDescending(p => p.NewsDate);
    }
}
```